# What are some websites to circumvent company firewall and view blocked sites? (not proxy)

Tags: proxy, firewall, restriction

I've been using these for some time. Each has its own limitations.

textise.net - It retrieves text content of the blocked site. I miss visual content, especially when there is text on images. I also miss empty placeholders for images and videos. Clickable tabs or "more" buttons hiding text are also unavailable.

web2pdfconvert - Hit or miss. Sometimes it doesn't work (from behind firewall). I don't know why.

icanprove.de - Opens a browser inside a browser. A great idea. I even donated. I wonder why there's no alternative (or is there?). The drawback is, some sites (esp. shopping) reject access from this site.

Are there any other sites like these? I'm a restricted user, so no browser extensions, no software install, no changing internet settings for me. All proxy sites are blocked as you might guess. I'm not a computer guy but copying and mimicking the contents of a site should not be so difficult, I presume.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Search for "free vpn" and look for something that works best in your country or with the speed or other constraints that you have now.